# Dojo Application - How to

Tags: javascript, frameworks, dojo

Do any of you know any reasonably good resources containing methods and tutorials to help build a Dojo driven entirely AJAX application. I have been searching Google and the Dojo Toolkit web page however not many resources seem to tie everything together..

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what do you mean "entirely AJAX"? A one-page type of application?

Comment: Pretty much, yea.. I have some confirms regarding the number of functions and classes that will be used.. Not sure how to clean up, name space etc. Im hoping dojo provides a way to do this aswell as UI and dom manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with Dojo principles the best way would be studying working source code. There is nicely commented github project [dojo-boilerplate](https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate) to start with. It provides, well, boilerplate code to start building a single page javascript application including preconfigured build system. Unfortunately - afaik - build scripts based on Java neither node.js does not work under Windows as of now (not even under MinGW or Cygwin due path resolving issues).

Aforementioned branch uses AMD modules new to Dojo 1.7+, for previous Dojo version employing synchronous loader use [this branch](https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate/tree/1.6).

Also have a look at [build.dojotoolkit.org](http://build.dojotoolkit.org/) and check out its [source code](https://github.com/dojo/dwb).

Last but not least, don't forget books. You can find those I prefer in my [Career 2.0 Profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/phusick).

Comment: @DhaivatPandya can you please be more specific? The latest version of node.js I can find is 0.6.7. I was trying to build with node.js 0.6.6 for several hours on Windows. I also found an information 'Node 0.6 is not supported by Dojo yet.' (http://goo.gl/d4kRC), so I tried 0.5.4 w/o success. I gave up and currently I am building on Ubuntu in Virtual Box w/ noje.js 0.4.9.